# If in Partial URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, url

I know I can do this to match a full URL:

```
if(window.location.href == 'http://domain.com/folder/'){
    // Do something.
}
```

But how can I check for a partial URL like this?

```
if(window.location == '/folder/'){
    // Do something.
}
```

Comment: use string manipulation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly use

location.pathname this will return you path after hostname

Kindly refer this link

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_loc_pathname

Comment: This was the type of answer I was looking for. Thank you and thanks for posting a source link.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use normal string comparison or searching functions.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/folder/' !== -1) {
    // found partial match
}
```

Or, you can be more specific if you want it to be only at the top part of the path:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('http://domain.com/folder/' !== -1) {
    // found partial match
}
```

Or, if you want to see if the path starts with `"/folder/"`, you can use a regex on just the pathname:

```
if (window.location.pathname.test(/^\/folder\//)) {
    // pathname starts with /folder/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [location.pathname](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_pathname.asp).  This will return the url you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check to see if it is a substring of the window location (which we can convert to a string):

```
if((window.location.toString()).indexOf("/folder/") > -1){
    // do something
}
```